# How do I return a file to a user using Flask

Tags: python, file, flask, server, web-development-server

I am new to Flask and web dev in general, so bear with me.

I've been working on a Flask application where the user submits a file to a form, the server takes it and manipulates it, then returns the edited file back to the user. I am aware that the options are to manipulate the file in memory or store it on the server. I want to be able to return the file to the user, preferably using , but Im not sure which way to go. I already have the file object in my routes code, but am not sure where to go from there. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flask, how do I store a user submitted file temporarily to manipulate it and return it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220310/in-flask-how-do-i-store-a-user-submitted-file-temporarily-to-manipulate-it-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [flask.send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory).